# Postgresql ODBC driver 32 bit

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I need a help in postgres odbc driver setup. I have a Windows 2008 R2 server machine. I have SSRS running on this machine which is 32 bit.I need to install postgres odbc in the machine. Initially I installed a 64 bit Postgres odbc and I got the error saying that there is a mismatch between the driver and the application. Hence I downloaded a  32 bit driver in the machine. I tried to set it up through DSN but I could not find the Odbc driver in
the configuration section.How do I set up a 32 bit odbc driver in a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start->Run

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe
```

In newer Windows versions there's an "ODBC Administrator (32-bit)" Start menu entry for it.